# Wordpress how to use Ajax to show new data returned from successful insert_post()?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

After a successful Ajax insert of an entry, I would like to see what the ID and url of that same entry is and display it in a modal window without refreshing the page

Any way to get this data from success: function (response) {}? This is the code I have to make a new entry with ajax which works perfect:

```
  <script>
        
        $("#enquiry_email_form").on("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
 
            var form= $(this);
            var ajaxurl = form.data("url");
            var detail_info = {
                post_title: form.find("#post_title").val(),
                post_description: form.find("#post_description").val()
            }
 
            if(detail_info.post_title === "" || detail_info.post_description === "") {
                alert("Fields cannot be blank");
                return;
            }
 
            $.ajax({
 
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    post_details : detail_info,
                    action: 'save_post_details_form' // this is going to be used inside wordpress functions.php// *esto se utilizará dentro de las functions.php*
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Insert Failed" + error);
                },
      success: function(response) {
                modal.style.display = "block";  * abre la ventana modal*

                body.style.position = "static";
                body.style.height = "100%";
                body.style.overflow = "hidden";
                     
                     
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
<button id="btnModal">Abrir modal</button> 
<div id="tvesModal" class="modalContainer">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <span class="close">×</span> <h2>Modal</h2> * Ventana modal mostrar le url y ID generado *
 <p><?php ***echo $title_post, $url, $ID*** ?></p> 
 
 </div>
 </div>
```

Archive **funtions.php**

```
 function save_enquiry_form_action() {
     
        $post_title = $_POST['post_details']['post_title'];
        $post_description = $_POST['post_details']['post_description'];
        $args = [
            'post_title'=> $post_title,
            'post_content'=>$post_description,
            'post_status'=> 'publish',
            'post_type'=> 'post',
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'post_date'=> get_the_date()
        ];
     
        $is_post_inserted = wp_insert_post($args);
     
        if($is_post_inserted) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "failed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: So research how to get the last inserted row then you can return what you need from that row as json instead of just the simple strings you currently return

Comment: If it is easy to get the last row inserted but how would I pass it to JSON? Do you have any example?

Comment: You would use `json_encode()` on the object or array you want to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`wp_insert_post`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#return) function, it'll return the post id.

> It returns the post ID on success. The value 0 or WP_Error on failure.

---

- First you could initiate an empty array and call it, let's say, `$response` and populate it based on the returned value from `wp_insert_post` function.
- Then, we could use the id to get the permalink as well, using [`get_permalink`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/).
- And at last, we could send that array back to the client-side by using [`wp_send_json_success`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/) function.

So your code on the `php` side would be something like this:

```php
function save_enquiry_form_action() {

    $response = array(
    'error'             => '',
    'success'           => '',
    'post_id'           => '',
    'post_url'          => '',
  );
     
    $post_title       = sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_details']['post_title']);
    // Note we could have used 'sanitize_title()' function too!

    $post_description = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['post_details']['post_description']);

    $args = array(
            'post_title'   => $post_title,
            'post_content' => $post_description,
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_type'    => 'post',
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'post_date'    => get_the_date()
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

    if($post_id){
        $response['success']       = true;
        $response['error']         = false;
        $response['id']            = $post_id;
        $response['post_url']      = get_permalink($post_id);
    }else{
        $response['success']       = false;
        $response['error']         = true;
    }

    wp_send_json_success($response);

    exit;

}
```

**Note:**

- I've used [`sanitize_text_field`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) function to sanitize the `$_POST['post_details']['post_title']` value and [`sanitize_textarea_field`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/) function to sanitize the `$_POST['post_details']['post_description']` value.
- When you receive the response on the client-side, you could check for `$response['success']` and `$response['error']` values.

---

**On the javascript side**

As you can see on the following screenshot, data returns as `data object`.  To access data you could use `response.data.success`, `response.data.error`, `response.data.id` and `response.data.post_url`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any way to show the query of wp_send_json_success ($ response); in HTML? I am trying like this but without success:     `code     . $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',
    dataType: "json", // add data type
    data: { action : 'save_enquiry_form_action' },
    success: function( response ) {
        $.each( response, function( key, value ) {
            console.log( key, value ); // that's the posts data.
            $('#result_msg').html(key, value);
        } );
    }
}); `code

Comment: Just updated my answer. You could access the data like this:  `response.data.success`, `response.data.error`, `response.data.id` and `response.data.post_url`.